# Sort list in natural order in Groovy

Tags: groovy, natural-sort

Trying to sort(ascending order) the list of strings in natural / human readable order. Something like below.

```
def list = ['f3', 'f10', 'f1', 'f12', 'f2', 'f34', 'f22','f20','f50', 'f5']
list.sort()
```

I could find sample java code in GitHub. But looking for groovy way. Any help is appreciated.

**Desired output:**

```
f1, f2, f3, f5, f10, f12, f20, f22, f34, f50
```

Comment: what should be as a result?

Comment: @daggett, Just natural order(ascending), there are no confusing data in the above. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def list = ['f3', 'f10', 'f1', 'f12', 'f2', 'f34', 'f22','f20','f50', 'f5']
list.collect{ (it=~/\d+|\D+/).findAll() }.sort().collect{ it.join() }
```

Result:

```
[f1, f2, f3, f5, f10, f12, f20, f22, f34, f50]
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply appreciated.

Comment: This is not the question. The above may not work if there is preceeding zero for the number.

Comment: right. i did this code for sorting version numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
def list = ['f3', 'f10', 'f1', 'f12', 'f2', 'f34', 'f22','f20','f50', 'f5', 'f9']
list.sort { it[1..-1] as int }​
```

Results:

```
[f1, f2, f3, f5, f9, f10, f12, f20, f22, f34, f50]
```

Comment: dmahapatro, does it address the issue mentioned in the above answer?

Comment: It should. You can easily test that in groovy console. :) https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5171137738702848

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this `['g12','g01','g11','f3', 'f010', 'f01', 'f12', 'f2', 'f34', 'f22','f20','f50', 'f5', 'f9'] ` and seem to not work if there are different prefix. If same prefix, then yours works.

Comment: This scenario was never mentioned earlier. Please add this to your question and also add what do you expect to see as a result.

Comment: `list.sort { it[0] }.sort { it[1..-1] as int }​` will result `[f01, g01, f2, f03, f5, f09, f10, g11, f12, g12, f20, f22, f34, f50]` but I am not sure if this is what you expect.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I understand that solution depends on the question. That is why I marked earlier question as answered. But, as I go back try my data, new cases arriving, not sure if I need to open a new question. And to your updated comments with changed code, that is my expected as if you see that is in natural order i.e., `fxx` first and then `gxx`. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following comparator:

```
list.sort { a,b -> a[0] <=> b[0] == 0 ?
        (a[1..-1] as int) <=> (b[1..-1] as int) :
        a[0] <=> b[0]
}
```

It compares literals in the first place and when they are equal it compares numeric part. Using this method with list like:

```
['f3', 'f10', 'f1', 'f12', 'f2', 'f34', 'f22','f20','f50', 'f5', 'g1', 'g11', 'z0', 'a00', 'a01']
```

generates following result:

```
[a00, a01, f1, f2, f3, f5, f10, f12, f20, f22, f34, f50, g1, g11, z0]
```